# Not able to select profile in community

Tags: community

I've created a community. and Create a account Named : shipperman, under Account TAb.

I'm not able to select the profile.

[image]

Please Guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the same screenshot you posted can you goto members tab and see if the profiles you are looking to use are in the selected profile tab. Only those profiles come up in the Profile drop down you have shared in the screenshot

Comment: Yes. now I'm able to see. But still I'm not able to register from CommunitiesSelfReg. "Error:
The site is not enabled for registration.
"

Comment: Goto Setup --> Community Management for the community you are trying to configure. Then click on Administration - > Login and Registration and check the below setting --> Allow external users to self-register. If the check box before it is not selected please check it and save it and try the registration process agian

Answer (score 0):

Amol,
Verify that they have permission "Manage External Users" and make sure the account that new contact is related with must have an account owner that is assigned to a role.